# Why can't the rational expressing $\sqrt{x}$ be reducible?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am missing an obvious fact here. Suppose there is a rational that satisfies $({p \over q})^2$. All of the proofs I have read state this fraction has to be irreducible, that is, it has $gcd(p, q) = 1$.

Why can't the rational be reducible?

Comment: I think you are assuming that $\sqrt{x}$ is rational, so you can write it as a fraction $p/q$ in reduced form.

Comment: Without loss of generality it can be expressed as $p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.

Comment: You're not entirely wrong. It can be reducible. For example, $\frac{4}{2} = \sqrt{4}$. The point is not that it has to be irreducible, but rather that it can be irreducible if you want it to be.

Comment: If you prefer, you can alternately prove by induction that there exists some $k$ (typically a prime dividing $x$) such that for all $n$ we can cancel $k^n$. This means that the fraction could be reduced infinitely many times, which is not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\alpha$ be any rational. Then $\alpha$ **can** be expressed as $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ have no factor greater than $1$ in common.

If proof is needed, suppose we are given a rational $\frac{m}{n}$, where of course $n\ne 0$. Let $d$ be the largest integer that divides both $m$ and $n$. Then
$$\frac{m}{n}=\frac{m/d}{n/d}.$$
One can readily show that $\frac{m}{d}$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ have no factor greater than $1$ in common.

**Remark:** Recall the **structure** of the proof that, for example, $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. We start by assuming the contrary, that there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^2=3$.

Then by the argument above, we see that there must then be integers $p$ and $q$, such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2=3$. And now we proceed to our contradiction.

Comment: Ah I see, and since p and q aren't expressible in this form, there is no such rational : $(p/q)^2$?

Comment: @Jossie The contradiction is that (by the above) we can assume $\gcd(p,q)=1$, but then we reach the conclusion that $\gcd(p,q)>1$.